# Upgrading to devise 1.2, How to deal with Bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just upgraded to devise 1.2 and now I get this when I boot up (rails s):

```
[DEVISE] From version 1.2, there is no need to set your encryptor to bcrypt since encryptors are only enabled if you include :encryptable in your models. To update your app, please:

1) Remove config.encryptor from your initializer;
2) Add t.encryptable to your old migrations;
3) [Optional] Remove password_salt in a new recent migration. Bcrypt does not require it anymore.
```

Call me crazy but this isn't clear enough for me to want to mess with my user's table.

RE:

1. I commented out config.encryptor = :bcrypt - That was easy
2. What does this mean? I don't follow?
3. What does this mean?

Number 2 and 3 confuse me greatly. Do I need to make some type of migration to add encryptable? and remove password_salt? Not sure why I need encryptable, everything seems to be working right now as is?

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step two wants you to add t.encryptable to your migration. It would just be adding another column to your users table.
The next step wants you to remove the password_salt column in another migration since it is no longer needed. However this step is optional.

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/48c6eeee986d3f29/96bf6fc775609f5b) for more info.